# Material Design Icons Showing Completely Wrong Icons

Tags: javascript, html, css, material-design

I am asking this question because the others have not answered this problem for me.  The problem is that the icons that are supposed to display are random icons that are no where in my code.  For example, when I use:

```
<i class="md md-person"></i>
```

There is supposed to be a person-icon displayed there.  However, my web app displays a tablet or some kind of phone.

For more information, I am using Heroku to host my Node.js app with Express.

[This is what my icons look like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTpUm.png)

[This is what I want it to look like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qKtyH.png)

These are all my inclusions in my HTML:

```
<link href="assets/plugins/tablesaw/dist/tablesaw.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="assets/plugins/bootstrap-sweetalert/sweetalert2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="assets/plugins/nvd3/build/nv.d3.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="assets/css/core.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="assets/css/icons.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="assets/css/components.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="assets/css/pages.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="assets/css/menu.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="assets/css/responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="assets/css/_main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="assets/js/modernizr.min.js" type="566ead401d4a289a66320f2a-text/javascript"></script>
<script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js" type="566ead401d4a289a66320f2a-text/javascript"></script>
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="566ead401d4a289a66320f2a-text/javascript"></script>
<script src="assets/js/detect.js" type="566ead401d4a289a66320f2a-text/javascript"></script>
<script src="assets/js/fastclick.js" type="566ead401d4a289a66320f2a-text/javascript"></script>
<script src="assets/js/jquery.slimscroll.js" type="566ead401d4a289a66320f2a-text/javascript"></script>
<script src="assets/js/jquery.blockUI.js" type="566ead401d4a289a66320f2a-text/javascript"></script>
<script src="assets/js/waves.js" type="566ead401d4a289a66320f2a-text/javascript"></script>
<script src="assets/js/wow.min.js" type="566ead401d4a289a66320f2a-text/javascript"></script>
<script src="assets/js/jquery.nicescroll.js" type="566ead401d4a289a66320f2a-text/javascript"></script>
<script src="assets/js/jquery.scrollTo.min.js" type="566ead401d4a289a66320f2a-text/javascript"></script>
<script src="assets/plugins/switchery/switchery.min.js" type="566ead401d4a289a66320f2a-text/javascript"></script>
<script src="assets/js/jquery.core.js" type="566ead401d4a289a66320f2a-text/javascript"></script>
<script src="assets/js/jquery.app.js" type="566ead401d4a289a66320f2a-text/javascript"></script>
<script src="assets/js/_main.js" type="566ead401d4a289a66320f2a-text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/scripts/a2bd7673/cloudflare-static/rocket-loader.min.js" data-cf-settings="566ead401d4a289a66320f2a-|49" defer=""></script>
```

I have also tried linking different versions of material-design-icons such as v1.0.1 with no change.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: There is a way for you to show the contents of `assets/css/icons.css` please?

Comment: Not real familiar with that, but there are a couple of ways to use it.  You can just use a Google WebFonts links and then in your tags use the textual name for the icon ?  `<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<i class="material-icons md-24">person</i>`

Answer (score 0):

Check it by inspecting the item to determine if any account is overwriting or not loading the source.

[image]